# Get Path from Selected File

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to get the full path of the file selected in the input.
Is it possible to get this directory?

I leave here the link of my input:[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgpolh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
 <div>
     <input type="file" (change)="showPreviewImage($event)">
     <img [src]="localUrl" *ngIf="localUrl" class="imgPlaceholder">
    </div>

 selectedFile:any;
  currentMapDetails:any;
  localUrl: any[];
    constructor() { }
    showPreviewImage(event: any) {
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                this.localUrl = event.target.result;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because of security concerns it is not possible to retrieve the file path. Also, it isn't really relevant information as generally the loaded file is to be viewed or sent to the server, neither thing requiring the full path to do.

What is your use case for needing the full path?

Comment: Unfortunately in my searches, they said that :( By selecting a file, I wanted to get the full path and then get a link to the physical folder in which the file was selected.

Comment: Yes, it is impossible with a file. If you want to upload a folder I think you can get some more information but I think the same restriction would ultimately apply.

Answer (score 0):

All latest browser do not allow this for security reasons. Security stops for getting anything about client computer's file system.

Practically you will not be using file path to restore/download file on client location so it isn't helpful.

There is [File.mozFullPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/mozFullPath) in Mozilla but it is not available.

*A privileged exension to the File interface, the mozFullPath property contains the full pathname of the represented file. This property is only available from within browser  code or old-style XPCOM-based Firefox extensions. It is not available to web content.*